# rails console load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the following error when trying to run

```
rails c
```

I get the following load error:

```
$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 12401
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
load error: /Users/andrejfidel/Documents/project_2/.irbrc
NoMethodError: undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
/Users/andrejfidel/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-
dev/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-
2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork': undefined method 
`reject!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: rake rails:update:bin

Comment: I tried doing that, this is the error I get: `rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails:update:bin' (see --tasks)
Traceback (most recent call last):
/Users/andrejfidel/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0-dev/bin/rake: undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Can you successfully run `bundle install` on your project? I'd suggest adding more information to your question to help you provide guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You have `project_2/.irbrc`, which is an `irb` console config file, that is either taken from the other project, or just invalid.

Simply remove it and you are all set. You might try to tweak it, but at that level of ruby knowledge I would advise to remove it.

It is irrelevant to the project itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried doing what you said, but I can't seem to find the file, I don't see it in my finder window (I do have hidden files enabled), nor can I delete is using "rm /Users/andrejfidel/Documents/project_2/.irbrc", the console returns "No such file or directory."